# Multi-language support without altering database structure

Tags: database, multilingual, erd

I have a question regarding support for languages on a website.

What is the best way to structure a database, while using multiple languages? For example, while creating a database schema that has an agenda table, a news table and a products table. All of these components have a description and a title.

The structure then would be:

- **Agenda**(id, title, description)
- **News**(id, title, description)
- **Products**(id, title, description)

Normally, I create a languages table. Every aforementioned table would get an extra column; language_id.

That means every translation of a record gets inserted again, using a different ID. The advantage of this method is that you can add multiple languages , without altering the database (you can just add a new row in the newly created language table, and insert a corresponding language_id in the news/agenda/products table).

Know I am aware of the fact that this is very cumbersome. The rows that basically have the same content - only in a different translation - have no way of knowing they are the same.

I have seen many approaches, like using a 'translation' table. So you'd get an extra news_translation, products_translation and a agenda_translation.

Is there another solution for this, without the need of adding a translation table for every component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ultimate generalisation would be to have a `text_field` table.  Store your text in there instead of in your dimension tables (your dimension tables just have foreign keys to the text field table).  Then you can have one column per language, or one row per language, as suits your needs.  I also recommend having the primary key include something intrinsically meaningful, like (TableID, FieldID)

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! This would however not solve having multiple text fields that need translation per row (like a title, description, maybe additional tags etc). At least, from your example I couldn't figure that out totally.

Comment: Instead of a title field and a description field you have two foreign key fields to the text table.  That table has a column for English, a column for French, a column for Spanish, etc.  In this way your one row points to two rows in the text table; one row in the text table is a title, another row in the text table is a description.  An additional consequence is that if many rows previously had the same tag, they can all point to the sane text table row.

Comment: That answer makes perfect sense. Thanks!